# Bind web service/Report Manager based on IP address AND hostname

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to get Apache installed on our main database/application server, and I'd like to give it its own IP address on a secondary NIC so I don't have to use a nonstandard port. This requires that I ensure everything else listening on port 80 is bound specifically to the primary IP address, rather than "all". This is no problem for the IIS sites, and I've already configured them appropriately.

The Reporting Services Configuration Manager seems to only give you the option of binding to a hostname *or* IP address, but not both. Is there a way around this via command line tools or direct editing of the config data, or will I need to add a third IP address and dedicate it to Reporting Services?

Comment: I only have a 2008 R2 copy to look at right now; it allows entering multiple entries in the binding list. So yes, each individual item allows hostname or IP, but you can have multiple items. Is that missing in 2012?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @JonSeigel You can do that in 2012, but I want to have it listening only on one hostname on a specific IP address. Seems like I can only specify either a hostname (which listens on all IPs - this is how it's configured now), or an IP address (which won't cooperate with the name-based virtual hosts in IIS, I presume).

Comment: Hmmm... I see. I don't know how to do that. I guess Microsoft figures (somewhat correctly) that servers shouldn't be piled on a single box like this. :) But I assume you would have separated them already if you had that freedom.

Comment: Normally I'd agree, but we deliberately built this thing to be a pretty beefy scale-up type of box for our application/data-tier needs. 64GB, 16 cores, etc. And I think it'll take up to 256 GB or so if we need it.